# Extracting values from python dictionaries with array of dicts

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I this data structure, but seem to be having a bit of a mental block. I can't work out how to get the values for the size keys in the dicts.

```
dups = {'2222': [{'Book': 'Lord of the Rings', 'size': '100'},
                 {'Book': 'Woman in Black', 'size': '800'}],
        '3333': [{'Book': 'The Hobbit', 'size': '500'},
                 {'Book': '100 Dalmations', 'size': '600'}]}
```

I've tried this:

```
for i in dups:
    book = i[1]
        for size in book
        print size'['size']
```

But that does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
for i in dups:
    book_list = dups[i]
    for book in book_list:
        print book['size']
```

`dups[i]` gives you the list, which you can iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .iteritems() to retrieve the value and keys while you are iterating:

```
>>> for key, value in dups.iteritems():
...     print key, value
...
3333 [{'Book': 'The Hobbit', 'size': '500'}, {'Book': '100 Dalmations', 'size': '600'}]
2222 [{'Book': 'Lord of the Rings', 'size': '100'}, {'Book': 'Woman in Black', 'size': '800'}]
>>>
```

And then you can nest a second loop in the loop to iterate over all keys and values again.